# Ignore property when converting object to json string but not when converting string to Object using by Jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I have a REST API that provides me a JSON. In the json I receive from the REST API, there is a ID property I want to read so I can do some checking on it. However, when I want to write back to the web server, the ID property must not be present in the response JSON string. So it has to be a write-only property, but simply changing a property to write-only prevents be to check what the value is of that property.

For example, I create a new product:

```
public class Product {
    
    //This feild should not be ignore when I convert JSON to object. 
    // But the same one should be ignore when I convert the object to Json
    @JsonProperty
    public String id;
    
    @JsonProperty
    public String name;
   
}
```

GET response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Product1"
}
```

POST Wrong:

```
{
  "id": 1, <-- This should be in the response
  "name": "Product1"
}
```

POST should be:

```
{
  "name": "Product1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a certain field from being serialized, you can use [`access`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#access()) attribute of the `@JsonProperty` annotation by assigning it to `JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY`.

```
public static class Product {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public String id;
    public String name;
    
    // getters, setters
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
String incomingJson = """
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product1"
    }
    """;
        
Product product = mapper.readValue(incomingJson, Product.class);
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(product);
System.out.println(result);
```

*Output:*

```
{"name":"Product1"}
```